# Why is there a different between value in the memory and value in my ruby program?

Tags: ruby, memory-management

My code:

```
require 'ffi'
......
str = FFI::MemoryPointer.from_string(gets.chomp)
Memory::write(handle, addr, str, str.size, write)
```

I enter '1234', but it is '875770417' in the memory when I start Cheat Engine to view memory.

How do I solve it?

Answer (score 4):

`875770417` is `0b00110100 0b001100110b 00110010 0b00110001` (binary), or `0x34 0x33 0x32 0x31` (hex).  These are the ASCII codes for the string "4321".

I'm not familiar with Cheat Engine, so I'm not sure why it's reversed (I'd guess it's related to endianness), but when you look at memory in a raw fashion you really need to be aware of what you're looking at and for.  If you look at decimal data, it's up to you to interpret it correctly, the computer doesn't know what the raw numbers mean.

Comment: how do i make '875770417' into '1234' ? what functions can do it ?

Comment: @HaoHuang, you should convert 1234 into smth like 256*4 + 210 == 0x00 0x00 0x04 0xD2 == "\x00\x00\x04\xD2". That is smth like `["1234".to_i].pack("I") => "\xD2\x04\x00\x00"`